# How to plot a heatmap under a curve?

Tags: visualization, plotting, matplotlib

If I were to have a data for a one-dimensional system evolving in time, essentially a two-dimensional array, and the array at each point in time is of the same size, how would I produce something like this:

[image: Example]

(Taken from *Turing’s model for biological pattern formation and the robustness problem* by Maini et al., 2012)

I have tried to replicate this with *matplotlib* by resizing (or rather synthesising) each instance in time to an array of specific length, according to the growth of the domain, and filling the rest of the array with NaNs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 750
x = []

t = np.linspace(0, N, N)

def asize(i, N):        # Computes the necessary size of the array
    return int(N*np.exp(2*(i-N)/N))

for i in range(N):      # Concatenating data with whitespace 
    x.append(np.concatenate((np.sin(np.linspace(0,3*np.pi,asize(i,N)))**2,
                             np.NaN*np.zeros(N-asize(i,N)))))


x = np.transpose(np.array(x))
plt.imshow(x, cmap = 'Spectral_r', origin = 'lower')
plt.plot(t, N*np.exp(2*(t-N)/N), c='white', lw = 2)     # Making the boundary smoother
plt.axis([0,N,0,N])
plt.xlabel('$t$')
plt.ylabel('$x$')
plt.xticks([0,250,500,750])
plt.yticks([0,250,500,750])
plt.show()
```

[image: Attempt]

Naturally, with actual data this method would be even more tedious, requiring to somehow squish the arrays. Is there a more reasonable way of doing this with matplotlib, Mathematica or any other tool?

Comment: If are able to explain how the original figure is obtained, maybe we can help you with how to do it.

Comment: It is a simulation of a system on a 1D domain using finite differences. The growth of the domain is supposedly achieved by changing the value of a parameter with time, so the actual number of points doesn't change. The problem then is to "squeeze" this data under an appropriate growth curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35498876/3358223) in StackOverflow.

The main "trick" is to transform your grid before plotting. For example, using the following transformation

\begin{align}
&t' = t\, ,\\
&x' = x e^t\, ,
\end{align}

and then use $(t', x')$ for your plot with `contourf()` or `pcolormesh()`.

Following is a snippet showing the main idea.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t, x = np.pi*np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:100j]
val = x
new_x = x*np.exp(t)

# plt.contourf(t, new_x, val)
plt.pcolormesh(t, new_x, val)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("x")
plt.show()
```

And this is the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!